# React Router Dom with Typescript cannot GET

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have a simple react project based on TS and use webpack. My problem is that the Router is ok, everything is redirected correctly and work ok, but when i refresh the page I have Cannot GET error.

index.tsx

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Route exact path='/' component={Lessons}/> 
      <Route path='/watch/:name' component={CurrentLesson}/>      
    </div>
  </Router>
</div>,
document.getElementById("example"));
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./src/index.tsx",
output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    publicPath: '/'
},

plugins: [
  new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
],

devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
},

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/, 
          loader: "awesome-typescript-loader"
        }
      ]
},

externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
},

devServer: {
  historyApiFallback: true,
  hot: true
}};
```

I read that may be there is problem with the history but for webpack the recommendations was to put output.PublicPath and devServer.historyApiFallback and for react router to pass history object but since i use react router dom it already have a history object and something else is that when i write exact same project on pure ES6 without thats shity type bullshit everything works fine. I have istalled @types/react-router-dom 4.0.x version and react-router-dom 4.x.x version

Why when refresh i get that Cannot GET /watch/some-param

Answer (score 0):

The issue is **client side vs server side routing**. Navigating to a route in the front end (using `react-router` routes) is not the same as typing that URL into the address bar of your browser (or refreshing that address when you're on the page).

This has been addressed in a million other posts here on SO and elsewhere online so have a look into 'client vs server side routing in react-router'

Answer (score 0):

Thanx a lot Jayce444, i found article with the sentence you give me and i found that:

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writting manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually/36623117#36623117)

Which was very helpful. The problem is that I start webpack and on refresh or in manually inputed URL in the browser the React Router and React are reset and the first request from the browser is send to the backend.

In my case i start TS + React to Webpack which can't handle to send me index.html on the first request when the Router is still not loaded.

But when use only React I start it through react-scripts which have a handler for that situation and every time on refresh when the router is reseted the react-scripts send me index.html

Big Thanx for the search sentence "client vs server side routing in react-router"